# Getting an error when creating virtual env

Tags: opencv

```
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - sphinxcontrib==1.0=py35_0
  - requests==2.14.2=py35_0
  - rope==0.9.4=py35_1
  - pytorch==0.1.12=py35_0.1.12cu80
  - pylint==1.7.2=py35_0
  - nbconvert==5.2.1=py35_0
  - vc==14=0
  - libpng==1.6.30=vc14_1
  - numpy==1.13.1=py35_0
  - jsonschema==2.6.0=py35_0
  - alabaster==0.7.10=py35_0
  - simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35_1
  - entrypoints==0.2.3=py35_0
  - isort==4.2.15=py35_0
  - qt==5.6.2=vc14_6
  - setuptools==36.4.0=py35_1
  - mkl==2017.0.3=0
  - path.py==10.3.1=py35_0
  - babel==2.5.0=py35_0
  - icu==57.1=vc14_0
  - vs2015_runtime==14.0.25420=0
  - jedi==0.10.2=py35_2
  - jpeg==9b=vc14_0
```

Comment: Please provide **exactly** how you produced this error.  As it stands your error is not reproducible by any of us.  Also when you have a moment, please take the [tour] and please visit [ask].  As it currently stands, your question is at risk of being closed due to non-reproducible errors.

Answer (score 1):

its actually an error you can fix it by: conda update --all then conda env export --no-builds > env.yml  and then with regular installation via: conda env create -f env.yml

after this fix works you might also encounter an error with output: 'CondaValueError: prefix already exists: /home/user/anaconda3'

for this error you just need to open your .yml file and make sure the environment name is not 'base' or any other existing env name. THAT'S IT! I hope this works !